# Textarea inside an image

Tags: html, css, image, textarea

I need to create something where the outline of a phone covers a `textarea`.

This is the [img source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5Ksf.png) and my current code is:

*CSS:*

```
div.sms{
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0
    z-index:99;
}

div.sms img{
    width: 300px;
    height: 510px;
}

div.sms textarea{
    position: absolute;
}
```

*HTML:*

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-6 sms">
       <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/n5Ksf.png"/>
       <textarea rows="4"></textarea> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try to leave a js fiddle or something more into your description to better cover your problem

Comment: why not put the image behind the textbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could place the image as background of a wrapper `div` and simply position the `textarea` inside that wrapper with margins :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/tw4t1mgz/)**

```css
.wrap{
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/S66oEHW.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    height:500px;
    min-width:300px;
}
.wrap textarea{
    margin:75px 0 0 53px;
    width:183px;
    height:350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
    <textarea></textarea>
</div>
```